# MySql simple stored procedure misbehaving. Adds one row extra

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This simple stored procedure is supposed to take rows that were not updated, and insert them into another table. But the way this behaves is rather odd.

If I were to run the below procedure like below I get: `Error 1329 No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed`, but the rows get inserted.

**Sample table data**

```
"id"    "total" "vals"  "valLen"    "updated"
"1"     "0"     "0"     "0"         "1"
"2"     "0"     "1"     "1"         "0"
"3"     "0"     "1,2"   "2"         "0"
"4"     "0"     "1,2,3" "3"         "0"
```

**Note the placement of the fetch**

```
BEGIN
  #declare variable
  DECLARE procId, procTotal, proc INT(10);
  DECLARE procUpdated TINYINT(1);
  DECLARE procVals, procValLen VARCHAR(50);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE counter TINYINT(1);

  #declare cursor
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id, total, vals, valLen, updated
  FROM scores
  WHERE updated = 0;

  #declare handle 
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  #open cursor
  OPEN cur1;

  #starts the loop
  the_loop: LOOP

 FETCH cur1 INTO procId, procTotal, procVals, procValLen, procUpdated;

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;

     insert into scores (total) values (procId);

  END LOOP the_loop;

  CLOSE cur1;
END
```

If I were to run the procedure like below I get 1 extra row inserted. Note the change in the placement of the `FETCH`

**Sample table data**

```
"id"    "total" "vals"  "valLen"    "updated"
"1"     "0"     "0"     "0"         "1"
"2"     "0"     "1"     "1"         "0"
"3"     "0"     "1,2"   "2"         "0"
"4"     "0"     "1,2,3" "3"         "0"
```

**After running the below proc**

```
"id"    "total" "vals"  "valLen"    "updated"
"1"     "0"     "0"     "0"         "1"
"2"     "0"     "1"     "1"         "0"
"3"     "0"     "1,2"   "2"         "0"
"4"     "0"     "1,2,3" "3"         "0"
""      "4"     "0" "0"         "0"
""      "4"     "0" "0"         "0"
""      "3"     "0" "0"         "0"
""      "2"     "0" "0"         "0"
""      "1"     "0" "0"         "0"
```

**Note the placement of the fetch**

```
BEGIN
  #declare variable
  DECLARE procId, procTotal, proc INT(10);
  DECLARE procUpdated TINYINT(1);
  DECLARE procVals, procValLen VARCHAR(50);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE counter TINYINT(1);

  #declare cursor
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id, total, vals, valLen, updated
  FROM scores
  WHERE updated = 0;

  #declare handle 
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  #open cursor
  OPEN cur1;

  #starts the loop
  the_loop: LOOP



    IF done THEN
      LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;

FETCH cur1 INTO procId, procTotal, procVals, procValLen, procUpdated;

     insert into scores (total) values (procId);

  END LOOP the_loop;

  CLOSE cur1;
END
```

What is the way to solve this and get this running correctly.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Desired output is `select rows where updated = 0` into another table. But for testing, I'm using the same table. Also, there are other things that happen before the insert, which I've taken out for this question.